# Work around LocalEndPoint socket

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, unity-game-engine, ipv6

According to the topic [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-ios-and-ipv6-support.404938/page-2), current Unity3D 4.7.2 (release for supporting IpV6 on IOS) have a problem with using Socket.LocalEndPoint & Socket.RemoteEndPoint.
Any call to these will cause an exception in an IpV6 network.

So is there any other way to get these value? Or any work around in this situation?

Comment: Did you read this link? https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46545

Comment: I've read, but it's no help.
Our app can't work in ipV6-only network while using LocalEndPoint and RemoteEndPoint.